# Typo3: LDAP extension

Tags: ldap, typo3

I've upgraded a Typo3 10.4.36 with LDAP 3.6.0 to Typo3 11.5.27 with LDAP 3.7.1.
All OK but stangely on the newest version the LDAP status -> Frontend authentication gives me "LDAP authentication disabled".
I've searched through the LDAP extension options but found nothing regarding the auth. enabling

Thanks in advance for your reply,
Fabiano

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: go to Admin Tools -> Settings -> Extension configuration and configure LDAP from here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).